# Wordpress - I want to add a <div></div> with a Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to learn wordpress and php.

Basically, I want the

```
function draw_ad() {
    echo "IMAGE CODE INSIDE A DIV";
//       echoing an image inside a div -- StackOverflow does not allow me to post img tags : )
}

add_action('the_content', 'display_ad');
```

===

Basically, I want to add a picture and be able to manipulate the "left" and "top" css options... but with a plugin. So it will be like a strange picture that covers whatever the area on the screen that I want it to cover :P.

Yes, it is kind of sloppy, but that's what I was asked to do : P.

The `add_action('the_content', 'display_ad')` kind of does it, but it removes the whole content.

Is there a better way to do this?

Is there a way to tell the wordpress PLUGIN to add this , say, before the theme's header, and not content? (As in, be able to put this thing wherever you want to in the html body tags?

Thank you, guys!

Comment: please insert your code between two apostrophes -> `

Comment: Ok, now you are able to insert your image tags.

Answer (score 0):

From theme developing I am sure you can add code to the header and at the end of the body tag. (wp-header, wp-footer)

The best thing is to insert the picture tag at the end of the body and style it with `position:fixed;`. You don't need a div around the img tag.